# d3 function inside my attribute function (.attr("d", ... statement) breaks code (D3 Version 5 - Scatterplot )

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scatter-plot

I'm working with d3 version 5 to create a scatterplot.

The following code works smoothly.

```js
svg.selectAll(".point")
                .data(data)
                .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", "point")
                .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCross))                                         
                .attr("Fill",'steelblue')
                .attr("transform", function(d) {return 
                  "translate("+ x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; })
                });
```

But when I use d inside any function, it breaks the display. Even if I use almost the simplest function possible.

```js
svg.selectAll(".point")
                    .data(data)
                    .enter().append("path")
                    .attr("class", "point")
                    .attr("d", function(d) { return              
                      "d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCross)";}
                    .attr("Fill",'steelblue')
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {                        
                        return "translate(" 
                       + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"; })
                    });
```

Comment: 4 things: 1) you cannot have a line break after `return`; 2) you want to return a function, not a string; 3) you're missing a parenthesis. 4) you have to call the returned function. All that being said, it should be: `.attr("d", function(d){return d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCross)();})`.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, the error is not because of using d. The issue is all about not closing the function properly. Make sure you are opening and closing curly braces properly. Please try this.

```
svg.selectAll(".point")
            .data(data)
            .enter().append("path")
            .attr("class", "point")
            .attr("d", d3.symbol().type(d3.symbolCross))       
            .attr("Fill",'steelblue')
            .attr("transform", (d) => "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
```

Comment: There was no error when I used the code that didn't include a function in .attr() . such as the code you have above. It ran perfectly.  The error is when there is a function inside the .attr("d", function(d) { ....... } statement.